# Where is the controller in this simple AngularJs page?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-controller, angularjs-module

I am told that every AngularJS page with the ngApp directive has a controller, providing for $scope.  In the earliest, simplest example given by the [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/angular/) site the code has no ngController tag:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="">
    <p>Name : <input type="text" ng-model="name"></p>
    <h1>Hello {{name}}</h1>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

The page obviously works -- try it on the W3Schools link -- and has scope ($scope.name).  Is there always an implicit controller?

Thanks,
Jerome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no controller on this page. But `ng-controller` isn't the only directives that create a $scope. `ng-app` also creates a $scope and that is the $scope that `name` is on

A controller is just some code that interacts with a scope.

Comment: Good point. I would suggest not to follow w3school examples by the book. Most of the times they are not exhaustive or even wrong.

Comment: Per advice elsewhere in stackoverflow I put an ID on the DIV containing the ngApp (<div id='xx' ngApp>...) and then, in the console, called angular.element($('#xx')).scope(). One of the attributes is "name". This demonstrates to me the correctness of this reply.  Is this $scope for the ngApp or $rootScope?  Thanks for the reply.  Jerome.

Comment: I believe ng-app creates a child scope of `$rootScope` but it inherits from `$rootScope` so in most cases you can think of them as the same thing

Comment: @rob do look at my edit..actually when app module is empty angular just add variable to its `$rootScope`

Answer (score 3):

> No there is not implicit controller there, behind the scene its `$rootScope`

When you don't specified a `module` in angular `ng-app`, it will initialize angular on page with no `angular` module.

But as you don't provided the `ng-controller` here, Angular will create `$scope`, it will utilize `$rootScope`, & will create variable inside `$rootScope`.

Because whenever you wrote `ng-controller` directive on page. Angular creates and new scope from the parent `scope` using `$new(false)` method on the current running scope. In this case if we introduce `ng-controller` here then it could be `$rootScope.$new()`.

**Edit**

You could verify that the code has been added to the `$rootScope` by accessing the `$rootScope` using `angular.injector`

**Code**

```
function checkScopeValues() {
  var app = angular.element(document.getElementById('test')).injector();
  var rootScope = app.get('$rootScope');
  alert("value from rootScope " + rootScope.name);
}
```

[**Plunkr Here**](http://plnkr.co/edit/F2I7zESHlvJNXcgf9PgO?p=preview)

Comment: In a prior comment I used angular.element().scope() to get a $scope.  I haven't seen anything that lets me get $rootScope from a Javascript console.  Is there one?  Note: I traversed the value obtained from .scope() but don't see anything for $rootScope.

Comment: @JeromePMrozak have a look at my edit, I shown how you can find that variable in scope..I added the plunkr too..Your code works becuase `$rootScope` variable are accessible inside `$scope`

Comment: I used checkScopeValues() and it delivers the "name" variable just as angular.element().scope() does. I'll be looking at this for a while.  I don't know how to allocate a "green check answered" to two results.  But I'd give both if I could.

Comment: @JeromePMrozak Thanks.. I don;t really understand why my answer gets downvoted?

Answer (score 0):

well its just a simple two way binding in the UI, that virtually creates the controller itself and binds the $scope to your direcives: but in real world you would have to create a module and then inject the controller into it.This just gives you a taste of what AngularJS is, I found a very good tutorial by jenkov here, it will guide you through creating AngularJs app from scratch 
[Link to the Tutorial](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/angularjs/index.html)
 Also search for some AngularJs JsFiddle examples on google, you can find a lot of them to help you get started –